# riak search result excerpt

Tags: search, riak

Doeas anybody know if riaksearch has the ability to generate excerpt with highlight points in it similar to lucene does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Riak Search doesn't expose this functionality out of the box, but with a little work you can create a rough approximation.

Riak Search allows you to feed search results into a MapReduce job. If you do this, then your Map or Reduce function will also get a list of token positions in the document that matched the query (this is exposed as keydata, http://www.basho.com/search.php?q=keydata). Using these positions, you can write code to mark up the document or excerpt portions of text.

Comment: How is the situation as of now (March 2012)?

Answer (score 1):

I think this functionality will hardly ever be implemented in Riak since it's philisophy implies that it doesn't care about what exactly is stored in the values and therefore does not process them in any meaningful way except providing some metadata like indices.